# A cross-domain ONLY Client-Side XML Request?

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome-extension, client-side, xmlhttprequest

this is my frist question on Stackoverflow even if I'm a programmer since I remember and I've used this site since I was born (ok maybe not that long).
The reason why I never posted anything is that I always found a solution here, but now I have to ask help for this question:

How can you create a cross-domain for an XML file (who said HTTP?) ONLY Client-side?
- NO Server-side code allowed.

My problem comes from this: http://code.google.com/p/chrome-intl-time/
It is a chrome extension I did, a digital clock that gives you the time of about 130 timezones.
Works now reading the XML from the folder but as you (probably) know the timezones difference are not the same all over the year!
I'm suppose to grab this XML from sites like http://www.timegenie.com/ at least once a day but guess what, on Chrome extensions you can't use server side script and, well, I can imagine why.

But what if I wanted a simple RSS Reader for Chrome? HELP!

(There is the possibility that all this ends up on a hosted solution with a simple iframe on the extension. But it is worth for an extension so small?)

So anyone knows how to fetch an XML file across domains?
I don't, I'm puzzled. Help.
Thanks for all in advance and try to forget my terrible English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [Request cross-origin permissions](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html)

Comment: Bang! That is gonna do it, but what if it wasn't a Chrome extension? How could I normally call XML cross-domain client side?.BTW I check it out and tell you if it did the trick

Comment: It is impossible for JavaScript running in a webpage to access data on a different origin without (server side) permission from that origin, anything else would be a horrible security problem.

Comment: Well, if you have a system to make safe any response for instance stripping away javascript from it and gettin' only text, that could work isn't it?

Comment: Anyway, problem fixed. Thank you so much!If curious here is the Chrome extension: http://code.google.com/p/chrome-intl-time/

Comment: Yes, please just get only the text from my online banking, that would be safe…

Comment: Yes got it, but what if you could "give" permission to read XML files that you store at your domain?

Comment: You can (via [cors](http://caniuse.com/#)), but that requires the server to give permission and you specified client side only.

Comment: Yep, I see, I think that the best approach it is still Server-Side, by the way I do work normally on PHP and that's where I grow up so actually I always saw javascript as (hope no one get offended) spaghetti-code, not really the place where I would store my bank details... Still a Pure Safe XML transfer could work if based on safety rules, the rule now is just "stay at home, don't bother here"